# Merge a jinja2 base-child pair into a template

Tags: dynamic, jinja2

I would like to implement a plugin system for my jinja2-powered web app, but I miss the ability of jinja2 to resolve/merge a base-child pair into a new base template.
Here is the motivation behind this request:

Imagine that you have a base template with a header bar section in `layout.html`:

```
{% block menu_bar %}
<ul>
  <li>First</li>
  <li>Second</li>
{% block plugins_menu_items %}
{% endblock %}
</ul>
{% endblock %}
...
{% block content %}
{% endblock %}
```

A template of the web app can then simply use the following code to inject its contents into a unified layout:

```
{% extends layout %}
{% block content %}
Lorem Ipsum and so on
{% endblock %}
```

and this code just needs `layout` passed at render-time, as described in the [Jinja documentation](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#template-objects)

However, what if I would like the app to have a plugin that could extend the menu bar by messing with the `plugins_menu_items`, and doing so without the two templates (top base and the child) knowing that such plugin exists. IOW, I would like to have something like this:

```
base_layout = environment.get_template("layout.html")
layout_extension = environment.from_string(
    "{% extends layout %}{% block plugins_menu_items %}<li>Third</li>{% endblock %}")
extended_layout = layout_extension.resolve_extends(layout=base_layout)
child.render(layout=extended_layout)
```

However, I am missing the `resolve_extends` method or an alternative that would allow me to impersonate the base layout with an extended one.
How would you solve this situation, when you would like to have transparent template plugins?